# disable insert key for all but one applications

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xmodmap

I would like to disable the <kbd>insert</kbd> key on my keyboard, because I often hit it accidentaly when typing, and it messes up my text.

I found I can use `xmodmap` to disable insert key completely:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 106 ="
```

This works, but there is another problem. Turns out, `midnight commander` uses the <kbd>insert</kbd> key for entirely different purpose. Not for toggling overtype, as in text editor, but for selecting multiple files.

This feature in `mc` is actually useful, and I am using it quite often.

Is there any way to disable the <kbd>insert</kbd> key in text editors in its role as overtype ON/OFF, but to keep it in its second role as "selecting files" in `mc` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key send a different keysym (the symbolic name of the key that determines what key applications think it is), for example `F25`.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 106 = F25"
```

Configure mc to recognize `f25` as a binding for the `Mark` command: copy `/etc/mc.keymap` (or wherever the keymap you're using is located) to `~/.mc/mc.keymap` and change the line `Mark = insert; ctrl-t` to `Mark = insert; f25; ctrl-t`.

Comment: actually, for some weird reason, it does not work when I use `f25`. It works when I use `f19`, but then that does not solve my original problem, because when I accidentally press `insert`, `f19` actually prints `~`. I need `insert` key do do absolutely nothing, unless it is pressed in `mc`.

Answer (score 2):

Most of Midnight Commander's key-bindings are customizable. The feature you're talking about appears to be *Mark*, which is in the default keymap file, e.g., `/etc/mc.keymap`:

```
[panel]
Search = ctrl-s; alt-s
Mark = insert; ctrl-t
```

According to the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mc), if you provide your own keymap file (and make that the first one found), it will use *that* file instead of the system's keymap.  By assigning *Mark* to a different key-sequence, you can make `mc` ignore <kbd>Insert</kbd> in the case which causes problems.

You can see the other places where <kbd>Insert</kbd> is used in `mc` keymap files by

```
dpkg -L mc |xargs grep -i -n insert 2>/dev/null
```

which shows, for example, that it is used in `InsertOverwrite`.

```
Binary file /usr/bin/mc matches
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.emacs:81:Mark = insert; ctrl-t
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.emacs:302:InsertFile = f15
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.emacs:304:InsertOverwrite = insert
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.emacs:322:InsertLiteral = ctrl-q
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.emacs:365:Up = k; y; insert; up; ctrl-p
/etc/mc/mc.keymap:80:Mark = insert; ctrl-t
/etc/mc/mc.keymap:220:Store = ctrl-insert
/etc/mc/mc.keymap:221:Paste = shift-insert
/etc/mc/mc.keymap:302:InsertFile = f15
/etc/mc/mc.keymap:304:InsertOverwrite = insert
/etc/mc/mc.keymap:322:InsertLiteral = ctrl-q
/etc/mc/mc.keymap:362:Up = k; y; insert; up; ctrl-p
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.default:80:Mark = insert; ctrl-t
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.default:220:Store = ctrl-insert
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.default:221:Paste = shift-insert
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.default:302:InsertFile = f15
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.default:304:InsertOverwrite = insert
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.default:322:InsertLiteral = ctrl-q
/etc/mc/mc.keymap.default:362:Up = k; y; insert; up; ctrl-p
/etc/mc/mcedit.menu:450:I       Insert `Changelog' string
/etc/mc/mcedit.menu:467:i       Insert a out of command to cursor.
Binary file /usr/bin/mcview matches
Binary file /usr/bin/mcdiff matches
Binary file /usr/bin/mcedit matches
```

Comment: thanks, that is helpful. But I don't want to assign Mark to a different key-sequence. I would like to use "insert" key as Mark, while disabling insert (overtype ON/OFF) in other applications